# Wordpress Custom Post Types doesn't show in admin left sidebar menu

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I have a weird problem with one of my custom post type that doesn't show in left sidebar admin menu.

I declared 5 custom post types but the fifth doesn't show in left menu. Here it's the Clients post type that doesn't show. I made a lot of search about this, without success.

Thanks a lot for your help !

```
    /**
 * Custom Posts Types
 */

add_action('init', 'create_team_post_type');
function create_team_post_type() {
    register_post_type( 'phil_team',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __('Équipe'),
                'singular_name' => __('Individu'),
                'add_new' => __('Ajouter'),
                'add_new_item' => __('Ajouter un individu'),
                'view_item' => __('Voir individu'),
                'edit_item' => __('Modifier individu'),
                'search_items' => __('Rechercher un individu'),
                'not_found' => __('Individu non trouvé'),
                'not_found_in_trash' => __('Individu non trouvé dans la corbeille')
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'hierarchical' => false,
            'menu_position' => 21,
            'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'team'),
            'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail'),
            'show_ui' => true
        )
    );
}

add_action('init', 'create_projects_post_type');
function create_projects_post_type() {
    register_post_type( 'phil_projects',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __('Projets'),
                'singular_name' => __('Projet'),
                'add_new' => __('Ajouter'),
                'add_new_item' => __('Ajouter un projet'),
                'view_item' => __('Voir projet'),
                'edit_item' => __('Modifier projet'),
                'search_items' => __('Rechercher un projet'),
                'not_found' => __('Projet non trouvé'),
                'not_found_in_trash' => __('Projet non trouvé dans la corbeille')
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'menu_position' => 21,
            'query_var' => 'project',
            'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'who-we-help/our-work'),
            'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail'),
            'show_ui' => true
        )
    );

    $set = get_option('post_type_rules_flased_POST-TYPE-NAME-HERE');
    if ($set !== true){
       flush_rewrite_rules(false);
       update_option('post_type_rules_flased_POST-TYPE-NAME-HERE',true);
}
}

add_action('init', 'create_slideshow_post_type');
function create_slideshow_post_type() {
    register_post_type( 'phil_home_slideshow',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __('Slideshow'),
                'singular_name' => __('Image'),
                'add_new' => __('Ajouter'),
                'add_new_item' => __('Ajouter une image'),
                'view_item' => __('Voir image'),
                'edit_item' => __('Modifier image'),
                'search_items' => __('Rechercher une image'),
                'not_found' => __('Image non trouvé'),
                'not_found_in_trash' => __('Image non trouvé dans la corbeille')
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'hierarchical' => false,
            'menu_position' => 21,
            'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'slideshow'),
            'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail'),
            'show_ui' => true
        )
    );
}

add_action('init', 'create_home_boxes_post_type');
function create_home_boxes_post_type() {
    register_post_type( 'phil_home_boxes',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __('Boîtes page d\'accueil'),
                'singular_name' => __('Boîte'),
                'add_new' => __('Ajouter'),
                'add_new_item' => __('Ajouter une boîte'),
                'view_item' => __('Voir boîte'),
                'edit_item' => __('Modifier boîte'),
                'search_items' => __('Rechercher une boîte'),
                'not_found' => __('Boîte non trouvé'),
                'not_found_in_trash' => __('Boîte non trouvé dans la corbeille')
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'hierarchical' => false,
            'menu_position' => 21,
            'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail'),
            'show_ui' => true
        )
    );
}

add_action('init', 'create_clients_post_type');
function create_clients_post_type() {
    register_post_type( 'phil_clients',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __('Clients'),
                'singular_name' => __('Client'),
                'add_new' => __('Ajouter'),
                'add_new_item' => __('Ajouter un client'),
                'view_item' => __('Voir client'),
                'edit_item' => __('Modifier client'),
                'search_items' => __('Rechercher une client'),
                'not_found' => __('Client non trouvé'),
                'not_found_in_trash' => __('Client non trouvé dans la corbeille')
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'show_ui' => true,
            'hierarchical' => false,
            'menu_position' => 21,
            'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail')
        )
    );
}
```

Answer (score 58):

This case does not seem to be the same, but one reason for not showing in the left admin menu is the length of the name of the post type is longer than 20 characters
[Function Reference/register post type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type)

Comment: This was my case. Thank you. What a crazy limit - 20 is like nothing!

Comment: Thank you for this. Wordpress did not indicate me that that was the issue.

Comment: Thanks! That was my problem too.

Comment: You saved my life... Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

In my case I was able to see the custom post type in the left side bar as administrator but the authors could not.
What I had to change was the **capability_type** from *page* to *post* since that's what authors are enabled to by default.

```
'capability_type' => 'post'
```

This line goes in the in the **$args** array of the definition of the post type.

Comment: Thanks. this was the issue in my case. It had been set to a custom value and changing to 'post' fixed the issue.

Answer (score 4):

if you use User Role Editor plugin it is sometimes needed to add ("Users" -> "User Role Editor" -> "Add Capability") some custom capabilities like: 'read', 'edit_post', 'delete_post', 'read_post' by hand to be able (to have rights) to see your custom post

Comment: This was my fix.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Add `'show_in_menu' => true,` after `'public' => true,`

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes this can be caused by the `menu_position` clashing with another menu position, or perhaps being hidden away by some other plugin. Try changing that value.

`'menu_position' => 21`

Comment: Sidenote: this is only an issue in older WP versions.

Comment: This was still an issue for me in 4.9.10

Answer (score 2):

I just had the same issue, and nothing helps for me. But I found a solution (temporally), I go to `Appearance > Customize` and there it was, `Custom post type` was there. I don't know what causes this bug because in localhost everything was fine, but on live, it's not working.

Answer (score 2):

You may have just set the required attributes to false. These attributes must be set to `true` in order for the custom post type to show in the WordPress admin menu on the left:

```
'show_ui' => true,
'show_in_menu' => true,
```

Answer (score 2):

If this is only happening on one specific user account, but it's working on all others, then you'll need to have the user that this is happening to do the following:

From the menus page, go to "screen options" in the top right corner, and then check and uncheck your custom post type. This refreshes something internally, and fixes the problem. If upon clicking "screen options", you don't see your custom post type listed, then you need to use one of the other solutions posted here.

Comment: This was the case for myself as well.

Answer (score 1):

Add code on your `function.php`.

See the below defined image:

```
add_action('init', 'create_team_post_type');
function create_team_post_type() {
    register_post_type( 'phil_team',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __('Équipe'),
                'singular_name' => __('Individu'),
                'add_new' => __('Ajouter'),
                'add_new_item' => __('Ajouter un individu'),
                'view_item' => __('Voir individu'),
                'edit_item' => __('Modifier individu'),
                'search_items' => __('Rechercher un individu'),
                'not_found' => __('Individu non trouvé'),
                'not_found_in_trash' => __('Individu non trouvé dans la corbeille')
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'has_archive' => true,
            'hierarchical' => false,
            'menu_position' => 21,
            'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'team'),
            'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail'),
            'show_ui' => true
        )
    );
}

add_action('init', 'create_projects_post_type');
function create_projects_post_type() {
    register_post_type( 'phil_projects',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __('Projets'),
                'singular_name' => __('Projet'),
                'add_new' => __('Ajouter'),
                'add_new_item' => __('Ajouter un projet'),
                'view_item' => __('Voir projet'),
                'edit_item' => __('Modifier projet'),
                'search_items' => __('Rechercher un projet'),
                'not_found' => __('Projet non trouvé'),
                'not_found_in_trash' => __('Projet non trouvé dans la corbeille')
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'has_archive' => true,
            'menu_position' => 21,
            'query_var' => 'project',
            'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'who-we-help/our-work'),
            'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail'),
            'show_ui' => true
        )
    );

    $set = get_option('post_type_rules_flased_POST-TYPE-NAME-HERE');
    if ($set !== true){
       flush_rewrite_rules(false);
       update_option('post_type_rules_flased_POST-TYPE-NAME-HERE',true);
}
}

add_action('init', 'create_slideshow_post_type');
function create_slideshow_post_type() {
    register_post_type( 'phil_home_slideshow',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __('Slideshow'),
                'singular_name' => __('Image'),
                'add_new' => __('Ajouter'),
                'add_new_item' => __('Ajouter une image'),
                'view_item' => __('Voir image'),
                'edit_item' => __('Modifier image'),
                'search_items' => __('Rechercher une image'),
                'not_found' => __('Image non trouvé'),
                'not_found_in_trash' => __('Image non trouvé dans la corbeille')
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'has_archive' => true,
            'hierarchical' => false,
            'menu_position' => 21,
            'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'slideshow'),
            'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail'),
            'show_ui' => true
        )
    );
}

add_action('init', 'create_home_boxes_post_type');
function create_home_boxes_post_type() {
    register_post_type( 'phil_home_boxes',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __('Boîtes page d\'accueil'),
                'singular_name' => __('Boîte'),
                'add_new' => __('Ajouter'),
                'add_new_item' => __('Ajouter une boîte'),
                'view_item' => __('Voir boîte'),
                'edit_item' => __('Modifier boîte'),
                'search_items' => __('Rechercher une boîte'),
                'not_found' => __('Boîte non trouvé'),
                'not_found_in_trash' => __('Boîte non trouvé dans la corbeille')
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'has_archive' => true,
            'hierarchical' => false,
            'menu_position' => 21,
            'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail'),
            'show_ui' => true
        )
    );
}

add_action('init', 'create_clients_post_type');
function create_clients_post_type() {
    register_post_type( 'phil_clients',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __('Clients'),
                'singular_name' => __('Client'),
                'add_new' => __('Ajouter'),
                'add_new_item' => __('Ajouter un client'),
                'view_item' => __('Voir client'),
                'edit_item' => __('Modifier client'),
                'search_items' => __('Rechercher une client'),
                'not_found' => __('Client non trouvé'),
                'not_found_in_trash' => __('Client non trouvé dans la corbeille')
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'has_archive' => true,
            'hierarchical' => false,
            'menu_position' => 21,
            'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail'),
            'show_ui' => true
        )
    );
}
```

[image]

Comment: if you have not add direct code in your function.php also you have use file in add code xxx.php and define in your function.php

Answer (score 0):

Your custom post type name accept only 20 charactor,
see below example, now it is showing in admin panel at left side
register_post_type( 'artedu_post_type', $args );

It was not visible when it was
register_post_type( 'arteducation_post_type', $args );

Answer (score 0):

Set `show_in_menu` option to true

```
'show_in_menu' => true
```

In my case i'm using online custom post type generator and for some reason the generated code set show_in_menu option to false

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was caused by a space in the key:
"Post type key. Must not exceed 20 characters and may only contain lowercase alphanumeric characters, dashes, and underscores."

Ref: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/

Answer (score -1):

Using [WP-CLI](https://wp-cli.org/) this job is easy. First create the desired custom post type:

```
wp scaffold post-type team-member \
  --label='Team Member' \
  --dashicon='id-alt' \
  --theme
```

At end, do not forget add to `functions.php` file:

```
cat << EOF | tee -a $(wp eval 'echo get_theme_file_path("functions.php") . "\n";')

/**
* Custom Post Types.
*/
require get_template_directory() . '/post-types/team-member.php';

EOF
```