# WordPress Advanced Custom Post not displaying in backend

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, custom-post-type, posts

Here is the code, the 5th and final one is not showing up in the ADMIN CP Panel. All the others are working fine, but when I try add a 5th one. Nothing shows up. Not sure if there is a limit or something, does not appear to be from what I have read.

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );
function create_post_type() {
    register_post_type( 'Slides',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'slides' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'slide' )
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'has_archive' => true,
        )
    );

    register_post_type( 'Programs',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'programs' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'program' )
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'has_archive' => true,
        )
    );

    register_post_type( 'Boards',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Boards' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'sponsor' )
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'has_archive' => true,
        )
    );
```

Comment: the boards custom post does not show up in the back end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code just work perfectly, you have just forget in your code at the end a closing bracket `}` and some errors in slug post types (in lowercase):

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );
function create_post_type() {
  register_post_type( 'slides', // <== here to lowercase (slug)
    array(
      'labels' => array(
        'name' => __( 'Slides' ), // <== here 1st letter uppercase
        'singular_name' => __( 'Slide' ) // <== here 1st letter uppercase
      ),
      'public' => true,
      'has_archive' => true,
    )
  );

    register_post_type( 'programs', // <== here to lowercase (slug)
    array(
      'labels' => array(
        'name' => __( 'Programs' ), // <== here 1st letter uppercase
        'singular_name' => __( 'Program' ) // <== here 1st letter uppercase
      ),
      'public' => true,
      'has_archive' => true,
    )
  );

    register_post_type( 'boards', // <== here to lowercase (slug)
    array(
      'labels' => array(
        'name' => __( 'Boards' ), 
        'singular_name' => __( 'Board' )  // <== here singular
      ),
      'public' => true,
      'has_archive' => true,
    )
  );
} // <== forgetted this
```

I have test your code on a test website and even your custom post "Boards" is showing and working:

[image: screen-cp-board]

> You may need to **flush the rewrite rules** by going on backend **permalinks** settings and simply click on save to regenerate Wordpress rewrite rules related to this new post types…

---

**Is there a limit for post types in WordPress?**
There is **no limit for number of different custom posts**. Try the example below that generates in a very compact code 10 custom posts with a for loop :

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );
function create_post_type() {
    $arr = array('abcdef','bcdefg','cdefgh','defghi','efghij','fghijk','ghijkl','hijklm','ijklmn','jklmno');
    for( $i = 0; $i < 10; $i++ ) {
        $slug = $arr[$i]; 
        $slugs = $arr[$i].'s';
        register_post_type( $slug,
            array( 
                'labels' => array(
                    'name' => $slugs,
                    'singular_name' => $slug ),
                'public' => true,
                'has_archive' => true ) 
        );
    }
}
```

[image]

References:

- [Developer WordPress - register_post_type() function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/)
- [Wordpress Custom Post Types doesn't show in admin left sidebar menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17051263/wordpress-custom-post-types-doesnt-show-in-admin-left-sidebar-menu)